# IIS Express http/https bindings not working correctly

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, https, iis-express

I have a solution with 6 projects in it. And for 2 of them I [enabled SSL](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api) in project properties.
The problem is, that when I start debugging, **all** my projects starts with **https**, even if they're not configured to use SSL.

E.g. before enabling SSL my project was accessible via `http://localhost:63684/`. Now, with https enabled I can access my project under `https://localhost:43000/`, but when I try to access this url: `http://localhost:63684/`, it automatically changes to `https://localhost:63684/` and I get the following error in the browser:

```
SSL connection error

ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
```

The same goes for the projects, which doesn't have SSL enabled and I can't access them.

`...\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` file has proper bindings:

```
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:63684:localhost" />
    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44300:localhost" />
</bindings>
```

And other 4 projects, which doesn't have SSL enabled, but are still automatically switched to https:

```
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:11483:localhost" />
</bindings>
```

I already tried to delete IISExpress folder, because I thought config is broken somehow, but it didn't help.

**Any ideas what causes automatically switching to https and how to fix it?**

BTW, I was following [this](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/02/implemnting-https-everywhere-in-asp-net-mvc-application/) article when implementing https in my 2 projects and my goal is to be able to use http when debugging locally and https when project is published to the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, that it was a Chrome problem, because I noticed, that on other browsers everything is working well. [This SO answer](https://superuser.com/a/881431) helped me to fix this issue.